# Keyword Error: calling as.geodata function in geoR with rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, geor

I am getting `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression` in a script I am working on.

I am using `rpy2` (and the R package `geoR`) in Python to work with a data table that is retrieved from a PostgreSQL database using R's database functions.  The data is spatial data with coordinates and 2 columns of numerical data that will be used in a geostatistical model.

After the database query call, the dataframe object x looks like this:

```
    easting northing location attrib1 attrib2    category
1  658394.3 204987.5       p1         4.91        26.17 soil
2  658657.1 205116.7       p2         4.85        27.43 soil
...
```

I create an object for the geoR functions like this:

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
geo = importr('geoR')

Calling the geoR function as

```
y=geo.as_geodata(x)
```

works, BUT without argument data.col, it assigns the location attribute as the data attribute.  (First column after coordinate attributes is default.)

Trying:

```
y=geo.as_geodata(x,geo.data_col="4:5")
```

produces:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

I can't seem to get around it. I have looked at a few posts here and looked around online, but I can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

Rpy2 is a bridge to Python, mapping Python types to R types whenever necessary.
Here you pass a parameter of value "4:5", that is a Python `str`. That parameter becomes an R `character` (a vector of strings in the R lingo).

When you write an R function call such as `foo(bar = 4:5)` what you are writing is R code as the value for the parameter`bar`, that code will be evaluated to give the actual parameter.

I'd think that what you want is:

```
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import IntVector
y=geo.as_geodata(x, data_col = IntVector((4,5)))
```

or

```
base = importr('base')
y=geo.as_geodata(x, data_col = base.c(4,5))
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply.  I had to move on to other projects, but have returned to this one.  I've gotten it working based on these replies.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is due to you trying to pass two columns to the `data_col` command. Here is a working example using the `meuse` dataset from the `gstat` package.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr 
geo = importr('geoR')
gstat= importr("gstat")
robjects.r("data(meuse)")
x = robjects.r("meuse")
y = geo.as_geodata(x,data_col=5,coords_col="1:2")
vario = geo.variog(y)
robjects.r.plot(vario)
```

However you will notice that the above doesn't work, because `geoR` doesn't seem to get the `coords.col` or the `data.col` arguments. I'm not sure why this is, but a workaround to this problem is to write a wrapping function.

```
robjects.r('''
geodata_python <- function(obj) {
        return(as.geodata(obj, data.col=5, coords.col=1:2))
}
''')
geodata_wrapper =  robjects.globalenv['geodata_python']
y = geodata_wrapper(x)
vario = geo.variog(y)
robjects.r.plot(vario)
```

Using the above method you can pass additional arguments to the `as.geodata` function within the `geodata_python` function within the `R` environment.

HTH